Why is "Entreprise PBR 2025" from Dassault using 1.0f - max(Fr(V, N), Fr(L, N)) for the Fresnel transmission instead of just 1.0f - Fr(L, N)?
Dassault Systèmes has a spec for their PBR material: Enterprise PBR 2025
I rewrite Eq. 72 for clarity:
CoatedBRDF(…) = GlitteryCoreBRDF(…) * (1.0f − clearcoatWeight * CoatReflectedLight) + ClearcoatBRDF() * clearcoatWeight * Fresnel(H, V)
I understand that the reason we multiply the GlitteryCoreBRDF by (1.0f - clearcoatWeight * CoatReflectedlight) is because only the transmitted part of the light goes through the coat layer to the glittery core so the GlitteryCore only gets 1.0f - CoatReflectedLight of the total incoming light.
The question is: why is CoatReflectedLight using max(Fresnel(V, N), Fresnel(L, N))) instead of just Fresnel(N, L)?

I believe it is just another way to preserve the Fresnel effect for both light incident ray and view incident ray, since the whole diffuse substrate radiance should go through:

The light chooses to refract into the coat and hits the substrate.
Reflected by the diffuse substrate.
The light chooses to refract out from the coat (which should be equivalent to view vector refracting into the coat).


 (from Mitsuba3 docs BSDF plastic)

Therefore, both 1. and 3. should have Fresnel term. However, in Mitsuba3, similar (is it?) materials like plastic tend to this term different from what you have listed in your post:
// from mistuba3 mitsuba3/src/bsdfs/plastic.cpp, `sample` function
value *= m_inv_eta_2 * (1.f - f_i) * (1.f - f_o) / prob_diffuse;

This should be the physically based way to incorporate both Fresnel terms, but my experiment suggests that it will make the diffuse substrate appear darker, see the following figures. So my answer (my guess), would be:

Use max to preserve both Fresnel terms, so that the appearance is generally correct.
max instead of the product makes the substrate looks brighter.

The following figures have subtle differences between each other, so it is suggested that you download them and check the differences by quick swapping. The Vader helmet in the following scene employs the plastic material.



max Fresnel
product F
F(N,L) only
F(N,V) only












Additional question: what's m_inv_eta_2 for in mitsuba's implementation? @Enigmatisms

I think it has something to do with non-symmetric scattering. See PBR-book v3 16.1 Non-symmetry Due to Refraction and Eric Veach Thesis Chapter 5 (5.2  Non-symmetry due to refraction).
